# Single script to run in both Windows batch and Linux Bash?

Tags: bash, batch-file

Is it possible to write a single script file which executes in both Windows (treated as .bat) and Linux (via Bash)?

I know the basic syntax of both, but didn't figure out. It could probably exploit some Bash's obscure syntax or some Windows batch processor glitch.

The command to execute may be just a single line to execute other script.

The motivation is to have just a single application boot command for both Windows and Linux.

**Update:** The need for system's "native" shell script is that it needs to pick the right interpreter version, conform to certain well-known environment variables etc. Installing additional environments like CygWin is not preferable - I'd like to keep the concept "download & run".

The only other language to consider for Windows is Windows Scripting Host - WSH, which is preset by default since 98.

Comment: Look into Perl or Python. Those are scripting languages available on both platforms.

Comment: groovy, python, ruby anyone?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257730/python-vs-groovy-vs-ruby-based-on-criteria-listed-in-question

Comment: Groovy would be great to have on all systems by default, I'd take it as a shell scripting lang. Maybe some day :)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/BYVoid/Batsh

Comment: A compelling use case for this is tutorials - to be able to just tell people "run this little script" without having to explain that "if you are on Windows, use this little script, but if you are on Linux or Mac, try this instead, which I haven't actually tested because I'm on Windows." Sadly Windows doesn't have basic unix-like commands like `cp` built in, or vice versa so writing two separate scripts may be pedagogically better than the advanced techniques shown here.

Comment: Actually, `cp test test2 || copy test test2` does work, although it also prints an error message (and a success message) on Windows. `rm test2 || del test2` produces only an error message, but again, does the job.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

What I have done is [use cmd’s label syntax as comment marker](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php). The label character, a colon (`:`), is equivalent to `true` in most POSIXish shells. If you immediately follow the label character by another character which can’t be used in a `GOTO`, then commenting your `cmd` script should not affect your `cmd` code.

The hack is to put lines of code after the character sequence “`:;`”. If you’re writing mostly one-liner scripts or, as may be the case, can write one line of `sh` for many lines of `cmd`, the following might be fine. Don’t forget that any use of `$?` must be before your next colon `:` because `:` resets `$?` to 0.

```
:; echo "Hi, I’m ${SHELL}."; exit $?
@ECHO OFF
ECHO I'm %COMSPEC%
```

A very contrived example of guarding `$?`:

```
:; false; ret=$?
:; [ ${ret} = 0 ] || { echo "Program failed with code ${ret}." >&2; exit 1; }
:; exit
ECHO CMD code.
```

Another idea for skipping over `cmd` code is to use [heredocs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04) so that `sh` treats the `cmd` code as an unused string and `cmd` interprets it. In this case, we make sure that our heredoc’s delimiter is both quoted (to stop `sh` from doing any sort of interpretation on its contents when running with `sh`) and starts with `:` so that `cmd` skips over it like any other line starting with `:`.

```
:; echo "I am ${SHELL}"
:<<"::CMDLITERAL"
ECHO I am %COMSPEC%
::CMDLITERAL
:; echo "And ${SHELL} is back!"
:; exit
ECHO And back to %COMSPEC%
```

Depending on your needs or coding style, interlacing `cmd` and `sh` code may or may not make sense. Using heredocs is one method to perform such interlacing. This could, however, be extended with the [`GOTO` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510832/429091):

```
:<<"::CMDLITERAL"
@ECHO OFF
GOTO :CMDSCRIPT
::CMDLITERAL

echo "I can write free-form ${SHELL} now!"
if :; then
  echo "This makes conditional constructs so much easier because"
  echo "they can now span multiple lines."
fi
exit $?

:CMDSCRIPT
ECHO Welcome to %COMSPEC%
```

Universal comments, of course, can be done with the character sequence `: #` or `:;#`. The space or semicolon are necessary because `sh` considers `#` to be part of a command name if it is not the first character of an identifier. For example, you might want to write universal comments in the first lines of your file before using the `GOTO` method to split your code. Then you can inform your reader of why your script is written so oddly:

```
: # This is a special script which intermixes both sh
: # and cmd code. It is written this way because it is
: # used in system() shell-outs directly in otherwise
: # portable code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510688
: # for details.
:; echo "This is ${SHELL}"; exit
@ECHO OFF
ECHO This is %COMSPEC%
```

Thus, some ideas and ways to accomplish `sh` and `cmd`-compatible scripts without serious side effects as far as I know (and without having `cmd` output `'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`).

Comment: Notice this requires the script to have `.cmd` extension, otherwise it will not run in Windows. Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you’re writing batch files, I would recommend just naming them `.cmd` and marking them executable. That way, executing the script from the default shell on either Windows or unix will work (only tested with bash). Because I cannot think of a way to include a shebang without making cmd complain loudly, you must always invoke the script via shell. I.e., be sure to use `execlp()` or `execvp()` (I think `system()` does this the “right” way for you) rather than `execl()` or `execv()` (these latter functions will only work on scripts with shebangs because they go more directly to the OS).

Comment: I omitted discussion about file extensions because I was writing my portable code in shellouts (e.g., [`<Exec/>` MSBuild Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd)) rather than as independent batch files. Maybe if I have some time in the future I’ll update the answer with the information in these comments…

Comment: Could always create it with `.cmd` extension, and also symlink it to have a `.sh` extension.

Answer (score 31):

**EDIT**

The [binki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623721/388389) is almost perfect but still can be improved:

```
:<<BATCH
    @echo off
    echo %PATH%
    exit /b
BATCH

echo $PATH
```

It uses again the `:` trick and the multi line comment. Looks like cmd.exe (at least on windows10) works without problems with the unix style EOLs so be sure that your script is converted into linux format. (same approach has been seen used before [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5543&p=40558#p40558) and [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5543&p=40558#p40558) ) . Though using shebang still will produce redundant output...

---

you can try this:

```
#|| goto :batch_part
 echo $PATH
#exiting the bash part
exit
:batch_part
 echo %PATH%
```

Probably you'll need to use `/r/n` as a new line instead of a unix style.If I remember correct the unix new line is not interpreted as a new line by `.bat` scripts.Another way is to create an `#.exe` file in the path that does do nothing in similar manner as my answer here:  [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)

Comment: `/r/n` at the end of lines will cause many headaches in the bash script unless you end each line with a `#` (i.e. `#/r/n`) - that way the `\r` will be treated as part of the comment and ignored.

Comment: Actually, I find that `# 2>NUL & ECHO Welcome to %COMSPEC%.` manages to hide the error about the `#` command not being found by `cmd`. This technique is useful when you need to write a standalone line that will only be executed by `cmd` (e.g., in a `Makefile`).

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to comment, but can only add an answer at the moment.

The techniques given are excellent and I use them also.

It is hard to retain a file which has two kinds of line breaks contained within it, that being `/n` for the bash part and `/r/n` for the windows part. Most editors try and enforce a common line break scheme by guessing what kind of file you are editing. Also most methods of transferring the file across the internet (particularly as a text or script file) will launder the line breaks, so you could start with one kind of line break and end up with the other. If you made assumptions about line breaks and then gave your script to someone else to use they might find it doesn't work for them.

The other problem is network mounted file systems (or CDs) that are shared between different system types (particularly where you can't control the software available to the user).

One should therefore use the DOS line break of `/r/n` and also protect the bash script from the DOS `/r` by putting a comment at the end of each line (`#`). You also cannot use line continuations in bash because the `/r` will cause them to break.

In this way whoever uses the script, and in whatever environment, it will then work.

I use this method in conjunction with making portable Makefiles!

Answer (score 10):

The previous answers seem to cover pretty much all the options and helped me a lot. I'm including this answer here just to demonstrate the mechanism I used to include both a Bash script and a Windows CMD script in the same file.

## LinuxWindowsScript.bat

```
echo >/dev/null # >nul & GOTO WINDOWS & rem ^
echo 'Processing for Linux'

# ***********************************************************
# * NOTE: If you modify this content, be sure to remove carriage returns (\r) 
# *       from the Linux part and leave them in together with the line feeds 
# *       (\n) for the Windows part. In summary:
# *           New lines in Linux: \n
# *           New lines in Windows: \r\n 
# ***********************************************************

# Do Linux Bash commands here... for example:
StartDir="$(pwd)"

# Then, when all Linux commands are complete, end the script with 'exit'...
exit 0

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

:WINDOWS
echo "Processing for Windows"

REM Do Windows CMD commands here... for example:
SET StartDir=%cd%

REM Then, when all Windows commands are complete... the script is done.
```

## Summary

### In Linux

The first line (`echo >/dev/null # >nul & GOTO WINDOWS & rem ^`) will be ignored and the script will flow through each line immediately following it until the `exit 0` command is executed. Once `exit 0` is reached, the script execution will end, ignoring the Windows commands below it.

### In Windows

The first line will execute the `GOTO WINDOWS` command, skipping the Linux commands immediately following it and continuing execution at the `:WINDOWS` line.

### Removing Carriage Returns in Windows

Since I was editing this file in Windows, I had to systematically remove the carriage returns (\r) from the Linux commands or else I got abnormal results when running the Bash portion. To do this, I opened the file in [***Notepad++***](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download) and did the following:

1. Turn on the option for viewing end of line characters (`View`> `Show Symbol` > `Show End of Line`). Carriage returns will then show as `CR` characters.
2. Do a Find & Replace (`Search` > `Replace...`) and check the `Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x...)` option.
3. Type `\r` in the `Find what :` field and blank out the `Replace with :` field so there's nothing in it.
4. Starting at the top of the file, click the `Replace` button until all of the carriage return (`CR`) characters have been removed from the top Linux portion. Be sure to leave the carriage return (`CR`) characters for the Windows portion.

The result should be that each Linux command ends in just a line feed (`LF`) and each Windows command ends in a carriage return and line feed (`CR` `LF`).

Comment: In Notepad++ just select *Edit > EOL conversion > LF*, no need to do such replacements. And there's no need to do that everytime, just set LF as default if necessary in Settings > Preferences. Otherwise [there are lots of ways to do CRLF conversion on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20368781/995714)

Answer (score 9):

The following works for me without any errors or error messages with Bash 4 and Windows 10, unlike the answers above.  I name the file "whatever.cmd", do `chmod +x` to make it executable in linux, and make it have unix line endings (`dos2unix`) to keep bash quiet.

```
:; if [ -z 0 ]; then
  @echo off
  goto :WINDOWS
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 <firstArg> <secondArg>"
  exit 1
fi

# bash stuff
exit

:WINDOWS
if [%2]==[] (
  SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  set usage="usage: %0 <firstArg> <secondArg>"
  @echo !usage:"=!
  exit /b 1
)

:: windows stuff
```

Answer (score 8):

You can share variables:

```
:;SET() { eval $1; }

SET var=value

:;echo $var
:;exit
ECHO %var%
```

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways of executing different commands on `bash` and `cmd` with the same script.

`cmd` will ignore lines that start with `:;`, as mentioned in other answers. It will also ignore the next line if the current line ends with the command `rem ^`, as the `^` character will escape the line break and the next line will be treated as a comment by `rem`.

As for making `bash` ignore the `cmd` lines, there are multiple ways. I have enumerated some ways to do that without breaking the  `cmd` commands:

## Non-existent `#` command (not recommended)

If there is no `#` command available on `cmd` when the script is run, we can do this:

```sh
# 2>nul & echo Hello cmd! & rem ^
echo 'Hello bash!' #
```

The `#` character at the beginning of the `cmd` line makes `bash` treat that line as a comment.

The `#` character at the end of the `bash` line is used to comment out the `\r` character, as Brian Tompsett pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27527230/2095561). Without this, `bash` will throw an error if the file has `\r\n` line endings, required by `cmd`.

By doing `# 2>nul`, we're tricking `cmd` to ignore the error of some non-existent `#` command, while still executing the command that follows.

***Don't use this solution if there is a `#` command available on the `PATH` or if you have no control over the commands available to `cmd`.***

---

## Using `echo` to ignore the `#` character on `cmd`

We can use `echo` with it's output redirected to insert `cmd` commands on `bash`'s commented out area:

```
echo >/dev/null # >nul & echo Hello cmd! & rem ^
echo 'Hello bash!' #
```

Since the `#` character has no special meaning on `cmd`, it is treated as a part of the text to `echo`. All we had to do is redirect the output of the `echo` command and insert other commands after it.

---

## Empty `#.bat` file

```
echo >/dev/null # 1>nul 2> #.bat
# & echo Hello cmd! & del #.bat & rem ^
echo 'Hello bash!' #
```

The `echo >/dev/null # 1>nul 2> #.bat` line creates an empty `#.bat` file while on `cmd` (or replaces existing `#.bat`, if any), and does nothing while on `bash`.

This file will be used by the `cmd` line(s) that follows even if there is some other `#` command on the `PATH`.

The `del #.bat` command on the `cmd`-specific code deletes the file that was created. You only have to do this on the last `cmd` line.

***Don't use this solution if a `#.bat` file could be on your current working directory, as that file will be erased.***

---

## Recomended: using [here-document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04) to ignore `cmd` commands on `bash`

```
:; echo 'Hello bash!';<<:
echo Hello cmd! & ^
:
```

By placing the `^` character at the end of the `cmd` line we're escaping the line break, and by using `:` as the here-document delimiter, the delimiter line contents will have no effect on `cmd`. That way, `cmd` will only execute its line after the `:` line is over, having the same behaviour as `bash`.

If you want to have multiple lines on both platforms and only execute them at the end of the block, you can do this:

```
:;( #
  :;  echo 'Hello'  #
  :;  echo 'bash!'  #
:; );<<'here-document delimiter'
(
      echo Hello
      echo cmd!
) & rem ^
here-document delimiter
```

As long as there is no `cmd` line with exactly `here-document delimiter`, this solution should work. You can change `here-document delimiter` to any other text.

---

In all of the presented solutions, ***the commands will only be executed after the last line***, making their behaviour consistent if they do the same thing on both platforms.

***Those solutions must be saved to files with `\r\n` as line breaks, otherwise they won't work on `cmd`.***

Comment: Better late than never... this helped me more than the other answers. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

I use this technique to create runnable jar files. Since the jar/zip file starts at the zip header, I can put a universal script to run this file at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh\n
@ 2>/dev/null # 2>nul & echo off & goto BOF\r\n
:\n
<shell commands go here with \n line endings>
exit\n
\r\n
:BOF\r\n
<cmd commands go here with \r\n line endings>\r\n
exit /B %errorlevel%\r\n
}
```

It is important to set the line endings as outlined above because they can cause issues on the different platforms. Also the goto statement will not work correctly in some cases if the proper line endings are missing around the jump label.

The technique above is what I use currently.
Below is an outdated version with an in-depth explaination:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
@ 2>/dev/null # 2>nul & echo off
:; alias ::=''
:: exec java -jar $JAVA_OPTS "$0" "$@"
:: exit
java -jar %JAVA_OPTS% "%~dpnx0" %*
exit /B
```

- The first line does echo off in cmd and doesn't print anything on sh. This is because the `@` in sh throws an error that is piped to `/dev/null` and after that a comment starts. On cmd the pipe to `/dev/null` fails because the file is not recognized on windows but since windows doesn't detect `#` as a comment the error is piped to `nul`. Then it does an echo off. Because the whole line is preceded by an `@` it doesn't get printet on cmd.
- The second one defines `::`, which starts a comment in cmd, to noop in sh. This has the benefit that `::` does not reset `$?` to `0`. It uses the "`:;` is a label" trick.
- Now I can prepend sh commands with `::` and they are ignored in cmd
- On `:: exit` the sh script ends and I can write cmd commands
- Only the first line (shebang) is problematic in cmd since it will print `command not found`.
  You have to decide yourself if you need it or not.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this for some of my Python package install scripts. Most things between sh and bat file are same but few things like error handling are different. One way to do this is as follows:

```
common.inc
----------
common statement1
common statement2
```

Then you call this from bash script:

```
linux.sh
--------
# do linux specific stuff
...
# call common code
source common.inc
```

Windows batch file looks like this:

```
windows.bat
-----------
REM do windows specific things
...
# call common code
call common.inc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my BashWin project at https://github.com/skanga/bashwin which uses BusyBox for most Unix commands

Answer (score 0):

Binki's answer was great, but stopped short of a solution for the shebang error output on Windows.

```
C:\>#!/bin/bash
'#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I found you can get windows to redirect the error output to null, with clever encoding of the line break. Windows honors the '/r/n' and '/n' line breaks, but not '/r'. So if we make the first line break '/r', Windows treats the first two lines as a single line, and redirects the error output to null.

```
#!/bin/bash
# > nul 2>&1
```

Windows will still echo that code, but at least it keeps the error output stream clean. MacOS and Linux treat these lines as separate, so the shebang is recognized and the next line is ignored as a comment. I tested this on macOS 13.2.1, Windows 10 22H2, and Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

The downside to this is that playing with line break encoding is just asking for trouble, at least on Windows. For example, Notepad creates new line breaks based on the style of the first line break. But PowerShell ISE uses the line breaks around the modified text to determine what style to use. And even if you get everything right, some scripting platforms will re-write line breaks based on the target OS.

Answer (score -6):

There is a platform independent build tools like Ant or Maven with xml syntax (based on Java).
So, you could rewrite all your scripts in Ant or Maven an run them despite os type.
Or you could just create Ant wrapper script, which will analyze os type and run appropriate bat or bash script.

Comment: That seems like a gross misuse of those tools. If you wanted to avoid the actual question (running in the native shell) then you should suggest a universal scripting language, like python, not a build tool that happens to be capable of being misused as a replacement for a proper scripting language.