# Use Python script as external tool in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, intellij-14, external-tools

I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate` and I'd like to run a Python script (in a Tomcat server) from within the IDE.

I did it on Windows but it's not cross platform and I think it's a trick...

This is what I did:

- I defined `C:\Python27\python.exe` as Program
- I added my script as a parameter : `initDB.py`

Screenshot:
[New external tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvlOx.png)

It works well on Windows but I have to redefine this path on my other computers and my collaborators must do it too.

So my question is: can I use a Python script as an external tool without specifying my script as a `parameter`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to improve the situation a bit.

As described in [Single script to run in both Windows batch and Linux Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510688/single-script-to-run-in-both-windows-batch-and-linux-bash), it is possible to create a single script that you can run as a Windows batch file and as a Linux bash file. You could for example create a file `/Freek/Scripts/initDB.cmd` with the following contents:

```
:; /usr/bin/python initDB.py; exit $?
C:\Programs\Python27\python.exe initDB.py
```

The definition of you external tool is stored in a well readable xml file. For example, on my Windows laptop it is in the file `C:\Users\Freek\.IdeaIC15\config\tools\External Tools.xml`, which contains:

```
<toolSet name="External Tools">
  <tool name="Test (Python)" description="Simple Python script" showInMainMenu="true"
        showInEditor="true" showInProject="true" showInSearchPopup="true" disabled="false"
        useConsole="true" showConsoleOnStdOut="false" showConsoleOnStdErr="false"
        synchronizeAfterRun="true">
    <exec>
      <option name="COMMAND" value="/Freek/Scripts/initDB.cmd" />
      <option name="PARAMETERS" />
      <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="/Freek/Scripts" />
    </exec>
  </tool>
</toolSet>
```

This file could be (partially) copied from one machine to another and does not contain any platform dependencies if you can decide on a common directory/link for all operating systems (like `/Freek/Scripts`, which also works on Windows).

Comment: It helped me a lot, Thank you.
Thank you to help me with my first question too.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you are able to get it to work.