# Selecting git executable in Jenkins Multi-configuration project depending on axis

Tags: linux, windows, git, jenkins

I've got a [Multi-configuration job](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) in Jenkins.

Currently it has 2 axes, one for build type with values "Debug" and "Release" another one with 2 values too, setting some preprocessor macros.

I'd like to add one more axis with build platform: Windows or Linux.

My project is stored in git, and the "Source code management" part of the Jenkins job configuration contains configured "Git executable", chosen from the drop-down list.

As I understand, this list is formed from global Jenkins settings. My Jenkins has 2 git executables configured, one for linux slaves, and one for windows slaves.

However, this multiconfig job uses only one executable, "Default", configured for Linux slaves.

This makes me keeping 2 Jenkins jobs, one for windows, and one for linux.
Some inconvenience of this setup is that build results appear in different locations.

Is there any way to choose this parameter depending on axis value?

Comment: Are you working with a pipeline script?

Comment: No, it is multiconfiguration job

Comment: If you were using a pipeline script/ groovy I could tell you how :)

Comment: It is in plans. So, please, be so kind! :) Also, instruction on proper connection to Gitlab-CE is also welcome (there are some notes about issues in README for Gitlab plugin)

Comment: @mrkernelpanic: I'm moving to the pipeline. Have already created declarative description: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47814891/704329. Could you describe, how to turn it into a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can override default git location in the settings of the node.

`Manage Jenkins` -> `Manage Nodes` -> select windows node -> `Configure` -> `Node properties` in the lower part of the page.

Then check "Tool locations" checkbox and add path for default Git.
Not sure, if spaces in paths are properly supported, didn't check.

[image]

Next tricky thing will be [development of universal scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623721/704329), that run both in Linux Bash and in Windows CMD.  Less tricky alternative is rewriting all my build scripts to some cross-platform language.