# How to implement a conditional package install for Windows and Linux containers in the same Dockerfile

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile

I want to use the same Dockerfile for Windows and Linux containers. It uses build arguments top define the base image like:

```
FROM $SDK_REPO:$SDK_VERSION AS build-env
```

It also defines a argument called $PLATFORM which is either *linux* or *windows*.

Now I want to install a package only when the image is build for linux.
I tried to use an if switch like:

```
RUN if [ $PLATFORM = linux ]; then apt-get update && apt-get install -y <mypackage>; fi
```

Obviously, this doesn't work on windows because its using bash syntax.

Is it somehow possible to use the same dockerfile both for windows and linux containers and to do an apt-get install only when my platform argument is linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found a way to do it by following the examples of this thread: [Single script to run in both Windows batch and Linux Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510688/single-script-to-run-in-both-windows-batch-and-linux-bash)

In my case, I use:

```
RUN :; apt-get update && apt-get install -y
```

This will execute only on Linux but be skipped on Windows.